# d(vector)/d(matrix) in neural-network-deep-learning context

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, gradient-descent, neural-networks

When learning about Neural Networks, you are bound to stumble upon the technique of backpropagation/gradient descent. To give a brief explanation of the scenario we are to look at,

$$L = g(Wx+b) = g(a).$$

L is a scalar, W is a matrix of appropriate size, x is a vector given as input, b is a vector of appropriate size. g is a function that takes a vector of appropriate size and evaluates a scalar.

**W and b are to be updated in the opposite direction of the gradient,    so that L can be minimized**.

Many textbooks, lectures and blogs, including [Speech and Language Processing (3rd ed. draft)](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/) or CS231n, [use notations(See page 5)](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/9.pdf) that look like this.

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial V} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial V}$$

here, L is the "loss function" defined above, a, z are vectors of appropriate size, and V is a matrix of parameters, like W discussed above. Overall this equation was written so that we may find the derivative of L by "the weights" V. From this, it seems only logical to assume that we may attempt to get $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$ in this manner.

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial a} \frac{\partial a}{\partial W}$$

**But here is the problem I have with both expressions: on the right-hand side, there is a derivation of a vector by a matrix.** Now, from [a few](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf) [sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) I know that the notation nor the multiplication of this Frankenstein is not defined rigorously, if it is defined at all.

Since we typically add $\eta \frac{\partial L}{\partial W}$ to $W$ directly, we must be following the Denominator-layout notation as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Denominator-layout_notation), but I can't seem to figure the $\partial a/\partial W$ part out. I did look over as many blogposts as I can, but virtually none of them actually *show* how the calculation should be done.

So my question is as follows.

> 1. Is that kind of notation(da/dW) even legal?
> 2. If it is legal, how should it be evaluated and multiplicated in this context? Can you give an example?
> 3. Is da/dW possible to evaluate without doing it term-by-term?(evaluating da/dW11, da/dW12, ... and compiling them up later in some way.) What about dL/dW?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $f$ is a function of $W$ then let the directional derivative $D_W f(W_0) = F(W_0,W) = \lim_{t \to 0\in \Bbb{R}} \frac{f(W_0+tW)-f(W_0)}{t}$ such that $f(W_0+tW) = f(W_0)+t F(W_0,W)+o(t)$

Comment: Yes, that is true, and might come in handy for answering question 1, but I strongly doubt it answers the other questions.

Comment: @reuns Yes, I am aware of that, but the problem is that I can't lay out the DDs in whatever manner I want to; everyone using NNs, except me, seems to be using the same method to lay out the gradient in a designated shape. I intended to ask *in what shape, in what manner the directional derivatives are laid out*, and how might I handle the multiplications and calculations in that notation.

Comment: If $L(W) = g(a(W))$ some matrix/vector valued functions/variables then $D_W L(W_0) = D_{D_Wa(W_0)}g(W_0)$. Let $T(v) = D_v g(b_0),b_0=a(W_0)$ then $D_W L(W_0)  = T(D_W a(W_0))$. 

Letting $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} = D_W L(W_0) , \frac{\partial g}{\partial a}  = T,\frac{\partial a}{\partial W} = D_W a(W_0)$ you get $\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} =
\frac{\partial g}{\partial a} .\frac{\partial a}{\partial W}$ where $.$ is not a multiplication but application of a linear map. Those notations are a mess, but it is hard to find clean notations.

Comment: @reuns Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tensors get involved (and $\frac{\partial \text{vector}}{\partial\text{matrix}}$ is a 3d tensor), it is useful to keep in mind that the chain rule actually states

$$ D[f\circ g](x_0) = D[f](g(x_0)) \circ D[g](x_0)  $$

I.e. the derivative of composition of functions is the composition of their derivatives. Now in the context of linear algebra, matrix multiplication "$\cdot$" is essentially the same as the composition "$\circ$" of linear maps, so we tend to write $D[f\circ g] = D[f]\cdot D[g]$ instead. However tensors can be combined linearly in many different ways, and this notation tends to come to its limits.

I recommend to take a look at http://www.matrixcalculus.org/ (CAS engine that can help to check formulas).

This paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.0197.pdf may also interest you.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, the chain rule can be problematic when the intermediate quantities ***cannot*** be expressed in matrix notation. But an easy way to solve your problem is to use *differentials*.

For typing convenience, define the vector 
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial a} = p
$$
Write the differential of $L$ in terms of $a$, then perform a change of variables to $W$.
$$\eqalign{
dL
 &= p:da \cr
 &= p:dW\,x \cr
 &= px^T:dW \cr
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} &= px^T \cr\cr
}$$

---

In the above derivation, a colon was used to denote the trace/Frobenius inner product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The cyclic property of the trace allows this product to be rearranged in different ways, e.g. 
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= AC^T:B &= B^TA:C \cr
A:B &= A^T:B^T &= B:A \cr
}$$